# Apostol's unexplained claim $\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}$ is 0 in Euler sum expansion of $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

On page 56 of Tom Apostol's Intro To Analytic Number Theory, he uses the Euler Summation formula (references also in this question) to expand the finite sum.

$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} $$

See image:

[image]

In the algebra manipulation he explains how for $s>1$ the expression $C(s) = 1 - \frac{1}{1-s} - s \int_1^\infty \frac{t-[t]}{t^{s+1}}dt$ tends to $\zeta(s)$.

However for $0<s<1$ he also mains the claim, but doesn't explain it.

In my understanding, the key element $\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}$ doesn't tend to 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I have asked a few others and we can't see how $C(s) = \zeta(s)$ for $0<s<1$.

Comment: The context specifies $0<s<1$ so $x^{1-s}$ tends to $0$ if $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Indeed $\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}$ doesn't tend to $0$ if $0 < s < 1$. But that's good, since the sum also grows without bound. Their difference has a finite limit. Now look at $C(s)$. The given expression is meromorphic on the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$, with only one simple pole, at $s = 1$. For $s > 1$ we have $C(s) = \zeta(s)$. By the identity theorem, this holds on the whole half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$ (minus the point $s = 1$ if you want).

Comment: I cannot see Apostol making the claim in your title.

Comment: @Lulu if $x=\frac{1}{2}$ for example, then $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ doesn't tend to 0 as x tends to infinity, surely?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  For some reason, I thought that $1-s$ would be negative, but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: thanks @daniel-fischer - I am not familiar with that kind of complex analysis so will continue to see what Apostol must have meant using only elementary reasoning

Comment: I have found that on page 55 Apostol gives a definition of zeta(s) using this C(s) for 0<s<1 .. without explanation. So that means I shouldn't have expected to derive C(s)=zeta(s) at this stage of the book. My apologies for not spotting this sooner. Let me know if I should delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From (7), use algebra to obtain
$$  \sum_{x \leq n} \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} = C(s) + O(x^{-s})  \text{.}  $$
Now take limits as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  As Apostol notes, "$x^{-s} \rightarrow 0$", so we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} \right) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \left( C(s) + O(x^{-s}) \right)  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} C(s) + \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}O(x^{-s})  \\
    &= C(s) + 0  \\
    &= C(s)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
(That both resulting limits exist justifies distributing the limit over the addition.)

---

Based on comments, a few words about analytic continuation.

There is a function $\zeta(z)$, Riemann's zeta function that is defined on $\Bbb{C} \smallsetminus \{1\}$.  This function has a simple pole at $1$.  It is meromorphic, or, what is the same thing, is holomorphic on any domain (open, connected subset of $\Bbb{C}$) excluding $1$.  There is a [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) for $\zeta(z)$ valid for $\Re(z) > 1$ because its abscissa of convergence is $\Re(z) = 1$.  (The pole prevents extension of the region of convergence of this series onto and to the left of this abscissa in a manner analogous to a pole preventing a larger radius of convergence for a power series.)  So, we have
$$  \zeta(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z} , \Re(z) > 1  \text{.}  $$
But $\zeta$ is defined on the rest of the complex plane (excluding $1$).  How does this happen?

Apostol is only interested is real $z$, and he finds another representation of $\zeta(s)$ for the strip $0 < s < 1$ by starting with the Dirichlet series, showing that it is identical to another meromorphic function, $C(s)$, on the half-line $s > 1$ and then observing that this new representation also converges on the strip $0 < s < 1$.  Then, using the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), $C(s)$ is the holomorphic (a.k.a. analytic) continuation of the Dirichlet series to the interval $0 < s < 1$.

In the background, this work is actually happening on $\Bbb{C}$.  $\zeta(z)$ is the continuation of the Dirichlet series.  The Dirichlet series converges on $\Re(z) > 1$.  Apostol's rewrite gives an expression, $C(z)$, that converges on $\Re(z) > 0$ and $z \neq 1$.  Using the identity theorem, $C(z)$ is the unique extension of $\zeta(z)$ from the half-plane $\Re(z) > 1$ to the (almost) half-plane $\Re(z) > 0$ and $z \neq 1$.

Comment: hi @Eric thanks but I can't see how $C(s) = \zeta(s)$ from this?

Comment: @TariqRashid It is $=\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s) > 1$ and meromorphic for $\Re(s) > 0$, thus it is the **analytic continuation** of $\zeta(s)$ there

Comment: hi @reuns I am not familiar with complex analysis to that level so I am trying to understand how Apostol would have reasoned it using elementary reasoning (he doesn't use complex analysis until later chapters)

Comment: @TariqRashid There is no other reasoning than the one I mentioned, analytic continuation is a fundamental concept, you need it.

Comment: (+1) for the edited version which addresses, I believe, the main issue. It is well written and completes the answer.

Comment: @TariqRashid : I've added a bit about the continuation.  This might be of use to you.

Comment: thanks @EricTowers I've marked as answered